# Transformation(s) with same limits and one-to-one mapping but different histogram shape

Tags: transformation

I generated random numbers in Excel $(0 < y < 2)$ such that their distribution in a histogram has the shape of a right triangle and is skewed right, not left.  I want a transformation or series of transformations to keep the same limits ($0$ and $2$) but change the shape to a triangle having zero skewness.  Also, there must be one-to-one mapping.  For example, $y = 1$ before transformation is $y = 1$ after transformation.  Is this even possible?  I can get close with $[(y^a - 1)/a] + b$, where $a = 0.875$ and $b = 1.1$, but might be going down the wrong path.  I'm not a mathematician obviously, so any ideas are appreciated.

=====

Sorry, I made mistakes in my original post.  I am revising it here and adding some images.

I generated random numbers in Excel (0 <= y <= 1) such that their distribution in a histogram has the shape of a right triangle and is skewed right.

[Histogram 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDpau.png)

I want a transformation or series of transformations to change the limits (0 and 2 instead of 0 and 1) and the histogram shape (zero skewness).  The distribution needs to be symmetric about y = 1 but not necessarily Gaussian.

[Histogram 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17N84.png)

Also, there must be linear mapping. For example, y = 0.5 and y = 0.75 before transformation are, respectively, y = 1 and y = 1.5 after transformation.

I don't think that all this is possible.  Am I wrong?

=====

Keeping the limits (0 and 1) or changing to any other ones, I don't think that it's possible to satisfy both remaining requirements (symmetry about the limits' midpoint; linear mapping).  For example, (y^a)/a, where a = 0.575, satisfies zero skewness but not linear mapping.

[Histogram 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PyQG.png)

[Nonlinear mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIs6X.png)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

Comment: Can you add some images for better context?

Comment: @Caedmon, I tried adding histogram images but apparently am not allowed to do so yet.

Comment: Never mind.  Click on "Histogram 1" and "Histogram 2" to see the images.